# d3pie.js formatted value displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3pie.js

Regarding - [d3pie.js](http://d3pie.org/) (plugin for [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)) ,

Suppose I have a `data` array of objects with both - `label` and `value` (number type) properties each one .

Currently the `value` is displayed as it is , I want to display it in specify format such - `$2,000` instead of `2000` and etc ..

I tried to add another property except `label` and `value` , say - `formattedValue`,  and then set it in -

```
"inner": {
    "format": "formattedValue"
}
```

but the d3pie doesn't consider it and no value displayed .

How could I archive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the plugin and it [doesn't look to support](https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie/blob/master/d3pie/d3pie.js#L811) passing your own format function.  A quick hack to switch those labels could be (after drawing the pie chart):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  d3.selectAll('.p0_segmentValue-inner')
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.select(this).text('$'+d.value.formatMoney(0));
    })
}, 200);
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/46nHqCWrjuemx805yU0X?p=preview).

The `formatMoney` prototype stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/16363).